# How to search for a specific value given by the user in an array in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch script wherein I need to ask the user for an input. After getting the input from the user it will now get the value and search for it inside the array. If it is inside it will proceed to a `goto`. If it fails, to a different `goto`.

Below is sample of my code

```
@echo off
set "Array[0]=830486600"
set "Array[1]=832180943"
set "Array[2]=867672488"
set "Array[3]=851091583"
set "Array[4]=105670350"
set "Array[5]=871749063"
set "Array[6]=831425861"
set "Array[7]=833386470"
set "Array[8]=845221250"
set "Array[9]=839863683"
set "Array[10]=837778733"
set "Array[11]=866184944"
set "Array[12]=863514631"
set "Array[13]=868073035"
set "Array[14]=841618088"
set /p code=Enter code: 

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set Array[') do (
    if "%code%" == "%%s"(
        goto breakit
    )else (
        goto breakit2
    )
)
pause


:breakit
echo inside!
pause
goto eof


:breakit2
echo not inside
pause
goto eof
```

Above is just a sample, but the problems that I have been facing is that, when the user types in its inputs with spaces it quits the program, it does not read the valid inputs even if it is the exact value inside the array it still does not read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct cause of your problem is that batch is quite sensitive at times to layout.

```
if "%code%" == "%%s"(
```

is quite literally taken as 'if `"%code%"` == `"%%s"(` ' - the second string is interpreted as *containing* the `(` and batch sees no "well, what do I do if the strings match?".

The solution to this is to add a separator like a <kbd>Space</kbd>

```
if "%code%" == "%%s" (
```

(Similarly, whereas `)else` works, `else(` doesn't so `) else (` is usually the format used)

Next problem: `goto` transfers execution to the destination label. It does not provide a return, so after the first comparison, execution is *transferred* to `:breakit[2]` and will then proceed from there. The consequence may be that `breakit` will then *proceed* to `breakit2`.

Or *would* were it not for the `goto eof`. There is no label `:eof` in your code (and nor should there be) - the *specific* syntax `goto :eof` (with the colon) means `go to end-of-physical-file` which terminates the routine.

You therefore need `call :breakit[2]` which executes a subroutine `breakit[2]`. The colon specifies that the subroutine is internal (within *this* batch) at label `:breakit[2]` (and the expectation is that it will terminate with `goto :eof` or `exit[/b]`). If the colon is missing, an attempt will be made to run the *executable* `breakit[2]`, even if the label `:breakit[2]` exists in the current code.

The final problem is that if `code` contains a <kbd>Space</kbd> then the `==` will attempt to match `code contents` against each of the strings loaded into the array. None will match since none of the strings in the array contain spaces.

If it is intended that a match be found if *any* of the (space, comma, semicolon) separated strings in `code` matches a string in `array` then the individual strings must be matched; hence use a `for` to iterate the strings in `code`.

Now that would mean that yes, you find a match - no doubt it would be useful to report which substring(s) matched rather than reporting simply that a match was found. To do this, you need to pass the string for which a match was found to `:breakit` and accumulate the string(s) found.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "Array[0]=830486600"
set "Array[1]=832180943"
set "Array[2]=867672488"
set "Array[3]=851091583"
set "Array[4]=105670350"
set "Array[5]=871749063"
set "Array[6]=831425861"
set "Array[7]=833386470"
set "Array[8]=845221250"
set "Array[9]=839863683"
set "Array[10]=837778733"
set "Array[11]=866184944"
set "Array[12]=863514631"
set "Array[13]=868073035"
set "Array[14]=841618088"
set /p code=Enter code:

SET "found="

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set Array[') do (
 FOR %%c IN (%code%) DO (
    if "%%c" == "%%s" (
        call :breakit "%%s"
    ) else (
        call :breakit2
    )
 )
)

IF DEFINED found ECHO strings found : %found%

goto :eof


:breakit
echo inside! (%1)
SET "found=%found% %1"
goto :eof


:breakit2
echo not inside
goto :eof
```

Note : for a `metavariable` (the loop-control variable in a `for` or the parameter number %0..%9 in a routine), including  `~` directly before the variable-name (`%%~s` or `%~1`) when retrieving its value will remove `"`any enclosing double quotes`"`

Comment: Can I change the echo part in breakit and breakit2 to a much more profound code? because what i really intend to do in breakit is create a folder if finds the input of the user inside the array. more or else like this, `:firstCreateFolder
md %firstFolder%
goto firstFileList` then if it does not it goes to another `goto` where in it asks an option. I dont if I should change the `call` part in the loop or the `:breakit` itself

Comment: Whatever you like. The issue simply is that if you `goto alabel`, then execution is transferred, whereas `call` saves the return location (the command following the `call`) to a stack. Reaching physical end-of-file returns execution to and removes the last location on the stack (`exit` does the same). If there's no more stack entries, the batch ends. You can spaghetti-code `goto`s forever if you want - just like assembler.

Answer (score 0):

You may simplify your code a lot if you move the desired values into the subscripts, that is:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "Array[830486600]=1"
set "Array[832180943]=1"
set "Array[867672488]=1"
set "Array[851091583]=1"
set "Array[105670350]=1"
set "Array[871749063]=1"
set "Array[831425861]=1"
set "Array[833386470]=1"
set "Array[845221250]=1"
set "Array[839863683]=1"
set "Array[837778733]=1"
set "Array[866184944]=1"
set "Array[863514631]=1"
set "Array[868073035]=1"
set "Array[841618088]=1"
set /p code=Enter code: 

if defined Array[%code%] (
   echo inside
) else (
   echo not inside
)
```